# How to remove black left line in neovim

Tags: neovim

When I open a python file, in the left hand side, there is an extra space as shown in the images, and this is only with python and the init.vim files.

[With a python file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNI8e.png)

[With other language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZYtS.png)

Comment: `:help signcolumn` is for you.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python filetype, a configuration file should probably define Vim option `signcolumn` with value = 1.

Load a Python file and check what is the value for `signcolumn` option with `:set signcolumn?` command.

You could disable this option in your configuration file (see `:help signcolumn`) :

- With Vimscript `init.vim` : `set signcolumn=no`
- With Lua `init.lua` : `vim.opt.signcolumn = 'no'`